# SpringJPA + Hibernate application causing MySQL Deadlock issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, deadlock

We are facing an issue which might by caused of resource exausted on AWS RDS.
As we checked the AWS RDS performance insights, we got several sql which have very high latency(even more thant 1 hour) And after we check the details on RDS by executing the sql query below

```
SELECT
  r.trx_id waiting_trx_id,
  r.trx_mysql_thread_id waiting_thread,
  r.trx_query waiting_query,
  b.trx_id blocking_trx_id,
  b.trx_mysql_thread_id blocking_thread,
  b.trx_query blocking_query
FROM information_schema.innodb_lock_waits w
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx b
  ON b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx r
  ON r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id;
```

We found that it might be caused by deadlock, found some sql statement like

```
select *** from table where id = *** for update
```

this one is blocked by

`update *** where id= ***`

and the update query is blocked by another update query, with the same id.

And as we checked the source code, there is no definition like we are using **select ** for update** statements.

Any suggestion we can move for next for the investigation?

Answer (score 0):

- Use the slowlog to find the queries that are taking a long time.
- Use `SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS;` to see the latest deadlock (if it actually deadlocked).

Present the results together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Then we can discuss further.